# PHP Tidy : Unexpected Special Characters after parsing

Tags: php, encoding, htmltidy

I am using PHP Tidy to reduce the document size while loading. Here is the code i am using for PHP Tidy.

```
$html_output = ob_get_clean();
$tidyConfig = array(
'indent' => false,
'hide-comments' =>true,
'join-classes'=>true,
'join-styles'=>true,
'drop-proprietary-attributes'=>true,
'output-html' => true,
'input-encoding' => 'utf8',
'output-encoding' => 'utf8',
'show-body-only' =>false,
'fix-backslash' => true,
'quote-marks' => true,
'wrap' => 1024,
'bare' => true);

echo tidy_parse_string($html_output, $tidyConfig);
```

[image: Php Tidy issue]

But I am getting some unexpected special characters for £. Instead of £ I am getting �, a question mark symbol at some places. At some places even spaces are replaced with �.

That image is the screen short of my output.First one is actually £ 3226797.99 and the later are some spaces.

Please suggest a solution.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We have this problem on one server due to character sets if you use `&pound;` instead of £ that will show up normally